# Triming the string in python

Tags: python, string

```
str1 = 'test1[2291];test2[NOT (Ready or Design)];test3[>=1 And NOT = 5]'
```

I want output from above string as below:

```
required_output = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

Removing the '[...;'

Comment: `[x.split('[')[0] for x in str1.split(';')]`

Comment: You can remove the parts in square bracket using regex, and split using semicolon. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result in many different ways, this is a sample solution that you can use:

```
str1 = 'test1[2291];test2[NOT (Ready or Design)];test3[>=1 And NOT = 5]'
result = []
for value in str1.split(";"):
    for word in value.split("["):
        if word.startswith("test"):
            result.append(word)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have to split the input string by semicolon first
- Then loop through and get index of square bracket
- Finally from 0th index to square bracket index get the data and append it to output list

```
    str1 = 'test1[2291];test2[NOT (Ready or Design)];test3[>=1 And NOT = 5]'
    output =[]

    for data in str1.split(';'):

        # Get index of square bracket
        index_of_square_bracket = data.find('[')

        # Get data from 0th index to square_bracket_index 
        data_without_square_bracket = data[0:index_of_square_bracket]

        output.append(data_without_square_bracket)

    output
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read and provides no description, can you please improve it and add some description ?

Comment: Hi Joao, I have included the description too

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is one way of doing it using Regex

```
import re 
test_string = 'test1[2291];test2[NOT (Ready or Design)];test3[>=1 And NOT = 5]'
res = re.findall(r'\w+', test_string) 
a= []
for word in res:
    if word.startswith("test"):
        a.append(word)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use re module and findall function:

```
import re

str1 = 'test1[2291];test2[NOT (Ready or Design)];test3[>=1 And NOT = 5]'

re.findall(r'test[0-9]+',str1)
```

Output

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```